# Cannot implicitly convert type Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceWatcher to DeviceWatcher

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core, removable-storage

I'm building an IoT app that needs to detect when a removable device was inserted and removed. I'm getting the following error when trying to create a DeviceWatcher object.

The `DeviceWatcher.CreateWatcher()` method is of type `DeviceWatcher`. Why would I be getting this error?

I'm not sure what the problem is and I don't know how to solve this. Can anyone give insight here?

```
DeviceWatcher watcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(DeviceClass.PortableStorageDevice);
```

**Error:**

*Cannot implicitly convert type 'Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceWatcher' to 'NamespaceName.DeviceWatcher'*

**Application Type:**

Windows 10 Background Application. Anniversary Edition.

**Manifest Capability:**

Removable Storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implicit variable declaration:

```
var watcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(DeviceClass.PortableStorageDevice);
```

## FURTHER EXPLANATION

By implicit declaration you are actually letting the compiler to do its magic (an intelligent guess) and derive the type of the variable, being declared based on the data type returned on the right. Basically your mistake is the assumption that the `watcher` variable should be of type `DeviceWatcher` but it isn't. At least not the one you've typed. Ther is a probably a conflict within your `using` statements, and the `DeviceWatcher` defaults to something different than `Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceWatcher` which is the correct type returned by the `DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher()`

Comment: This solves the issue but why do I need to implicitly declare it?

Comment: @Jnr because you have two classes named `DeviceWatcher` one in the namespace `NamespaceName.DeviceWatcher` in your code and one in `Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceWatcher` in the framework. When you typed in `DeviceWatcher` it used the one in your code, but the function retruns the one from the framework. using `var` makes it choose the one from the framework automaticly.

Answer (score 1):

Using `var` is one option.  You could also specify the namespace explicitly:

`Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceWatcher watcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(DeviceClass.PortableStorageDevice);`